# Terraform: Create new branch and create file within that branch

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

Using terraform, I'm trying to create a new branch within a repository.
Within that newly created branch, I am then trying to create a file.

The creation of the branch succeeds, but the creation of the file fails with following error:

> Error: Create repositroy file failed, repositoryID:
> 8249e650-45aa-4242-9bf5-a269cff844e7, branch: develop, file: test.yml.
> Error:  TF401021: 'develop' is not a valid name for a Git ref. Visit
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=800646 for more information on
> Git ref naming. │ Parameter name: newPush

This is the code I'm using to create the branch and file:

```
# create a new branch within the repo
resource "azuredevops_git_repository_branch" "new_branch" {
  repository_id = data.azuredevops_git_repository.myRepo.id
  name          = "develop"
  ref_branch    = data.azuredevops_git_repository.myRepo.default_branch
}

# within the newly created branch, add a test.yml file
resource "azuredevops_git_repository_file" "default_pipeline" {
  repository_id       = data.azuredevops_git_repository.myRepo.id
  file                = "test.yml"
  content             = file("${path.module}/assets/test.yml")
  branch              = azuredevops_git_repository_branch.new_branch.name
  commit_message      = "Add yml file via terraform"
  overwrite_on_create = true
}
```

Any idea what is wrong with the setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer in the meantime from one of the repo maintainers, you have to add 'refs/heads/' as a prefix in the branch tag:

```
resource "azuredevops_git_repository_file" "default_pipeline" {
  repository_id       = data.azuredevops_git_repository.myRepo.id
  file                = "test.yml"
  content             = file("${path.module}/assets/test.yml")
  branch              = format("refs/heads/%s", azuredevops_git_repository_branch.new_branch.name)
  commit_message      = "Add yml file via terraform"
  overwrite_on_create = true
}
```